# How to set the position of an image in pygame?

Tags: pygame, rect

I created an object called "alien" in my game. Uploaded the image for "alien" and used "get_rect()" to set its rect attributes.

Now I want to change the x-coordinate value of "alien". Which of the following two ways is correct?

`alien.x = ......` or `alien.rect.x = ......`

I saw in a textbook that the following codes are used:

```
alien.x = alien_width + 2 * alien_width * alien_number
alien.rect.x = alien.x
```

Why didn't the author directly use `alien.rect.x` to change the x-coordinate value of "alien"? Like:

```
alien.rect.x = alien_width + 2 * alien_width * alien_number
```

Why does there have to be `alien.x`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the answer is "it depends".  Some people's code maintains the position of the object at an internal `x` and `y`, using a `rect` to handle collisions.  Other code just maintains the `rect`, using the `rect.x` and `rect.y` if a single position is (ever) needed.

It's up to you really, but my advice is to keep it all inside a PyGame Rect, as this has benefits of easy collision detection, should you wish to use that down the track.

```
class Alien:

    def __init__( self, x, y, image ):
        self.image  = image
        self.rect   = image.get_rect()  # copy the image dimensions
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y                 # move to location

    def draw( self, window ):
        window.blit( self.image, self.rect )    # paint it
```

When it's time to move the `Alien`, you can just as easy adjust the rectangle as an `x` and `y`

```
class Alien:
    ...

    def moveBy( self, by_x, by_y ):
        self.rect.move_ip( by_x, by_y )

    def moveTo( self, x, y ):
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
```

Perhaps the author thought that having a separate `x` and `y` made the code easier to understand.  This is a paramount reason that effects programming style.  Program code is read many times more often than it is written, so often extra variables are included to illustrate the program flow better.

For example, like checking a mouse-click-event:

```
for event in pygame.event.get( ):
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        running = False
    elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
        handleGameClick( mouse2Board( event.pos ) )  # <-- HERE
```

Adding extra variables documents what's going on:

```
    elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
        mouse_click_coord = event.pos
        game_board_coord  = mouse2Board( mouse_click_coord )
        handleGameClick( game_board_coord )
```

Here it tells the reader that `event.pos` is a *co-ordinate* (so probably a pair of values), and is from the mouse.  Then it reenforces that the co-ordinate is then converted into a game-board space before being passed out to `handleGameClick()` for processing.

The two pieces of code have exactly the same outcome (and probably execution speed), but the second is much easier to follow.

IMHO one should ideally write code such that someone unfamiliar with the language (but still a programmer) can understand it without too much trouble.  This is why in my answers you wont see much "pythonic" loop-in-list creation like:

```
[[col +1 for col in row] for row in a]   # Taken from 10 vote answer
```

Because unless your very familiar with python syntax, it's unreadable.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Just a follow-up question: so `alien.x` and `alien.rect.x` can be used interchangeably in most cases then? If so, I would assume I could also use `alien.bottom/top/left/right` and `alien.rect.bottom/top/left/right` interchangeable? I wonder if there is a `screen.bottom/top/left/right` that I can use interchangeably with `screen.rect.bottom/top/left/right`? Just want to make sure these are legit object codes. Thanks!

Comment: @ Kingsley - Oops, so sorry, I just added the question. I tried to make paragraphs by pressing "enter" but it ended up posting my question prematurely...

Comment: @py_newbee - No, `alien.bottom` does not exist unless your code creates it.  Whereas a the PyGame `Rect` object defines and maintains `.bottom` as part of its internal code.  This is why it's easier to use a Rect, it maintains your bottom automatically.  If you do it yourself, there must be code to update `Alien.bottom` *every time* `Alien.y` is changed.